# PHP date issue, can't convert date before 1970-01-01

Tags: php, mysql, date

The following code outputs **`1970-01-01`** which is wrong.

```
<?php
$dob='17 Jan 1900';
$datetime = strtotime($dob);
$dob = date("Y-m-d", $datetime);
echo $dob;
?>
```

However it works fine with **`$dob = '17 Jan 2000';`**

Comment: Which PHP version and which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your PHP version allow it consider Using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of strtotime :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y','17 Jan 1900');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For PHP version between >= 5.2 and <= 5.3 simply use the DateTime constructor :

```
$date = new DateTime('17 Jan 1900');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I have **PHP Version 5.2.17**, and this method doesn't work. I need to find some other way.

Answer (score 5):

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from
>   01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

However, You can use the PHP [DateTIme](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.